# How to create a zip file of all PDF files in different subfolders?

Tags: macos, terminal, zip

My directory structure is as follows:

```
application
├── CV
│   └── CV.pdf
├── Cover_letter
│   └── Cover_letter.pdf
├── Transcripts
│   ├── BSC.pdf
│   └── MSC.pdf
└── references
    ├── ref1.pdf
    └── ref2.pdf
```

How do I zip these 7 PDF files from terminal so that I'll get an `application.zip` file, and if I extract it again all files land in just one folder?

Answer (score 1):

Zip (w/subdirs): **zip -r {myzip.zip} application**

Extract (excluding org. dir structure): **unzip -d {destination}**

Comment: -1, that doesn't achieve what the OP wants. Compressing the whole `application` folder will result in the same directory structure being extracted, and not all 7 PDFs in one folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-j` (junk names) option to have `zip` remove the absolute/relative path of each file added, and only add it by its name. In the most simple case, where your application folder only contains PDF files apart from the directories, use this:

```
zip -jr application.zip application/
```

If you have various files, you need to filter them and add them one-by-one, so for example, do this:

```
find application -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec zip -j application.zip {} \;
```

This will add all PDF files in the *`application`* directory by their basename only, to:

```
adding: Cover_letter.pdf (stored 0%)
adding: CV.pdf (stored 0%)
adding: ref1.pdf (stored 0%)
adding: ref2.pdf (stored 0%)
adding: BSC.pdf (stored 0%)
adding: MSC.pdf (stored 0%)
```